# Purpose of typealias

Tags: swift, type-alias

I thought that today I finally understood what is typealias for.

I didn't.

Let's take a look at an example:

```
typealias Graph = [String: [String]]

let futurama: Graph = [
    "you": ["bender", "hermes", "scruffy"],
    "bender": ["hubert", "zoidberh"],
    "hermes": ["hubert", "amy", "scruffy"],
    "hubert": ["mom", "fry"],
    "fry": ["leela"],
    "leela": ["brannigan", "nibbler", "scruffy"],
    "amy": ["kif"],
    "brannigan": ["kif"],
    "zoidberh": [],
    "kif": [],
    "mom": [],
    "nibbler": [],
    "scruffy": []
]

extension Graph {
    // Breadth First Search
    func bfs(from start: String, to finish: String) -> [String]? { 
        // Implementation of this graph algorithm here
    }
}

print(
    futurama.bfs(from: "you", to: "scruffy")?.joined(separator: " --> ") ?? "There is no pass, sorry"
)
```

Everything works just great.
Then I've made a small change:

```
let futurama: [String: [String]] = [
        "you": ["bender", "hermes", "scruffy"],
        "bender": ["hubert", "zoidberh"],
        ...
```

And I was expecting that now `futurama.bfs()` will not compile because `futurama` doesn't have method `bfs`. How clever it is, I was thinking, what a great design of the language!
But I was disappointed. Nothing changed. At all. The code still compiles and works.
So...

1. What is typealias for?
2. How to achieve the behaviour I was expecting for?

Comment: `extension Dictionary where Value: Collection, Value.Element: StringProtocol {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. typealias is literally for creating an "alias" (i.e. another name) for a type. You are not creating a new type, just another *name* for an existing type. From the [Language Reference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID361):

   > Type aliases do not create new types; they simply allow a name to refer to an existing type.

   Therefore, once you declared the typealias, `Graph` and `[String: [String]]` now refers to the same type. An extension on `Graph` is equivalent to an extension on `[String: [String]]`.
2. For your desired behaviour, you need to create a new type. For a `Graph`, I think a struct would be appropriate:

   ```
   struct Graph {
       ...
   }
   ```

   The `Graph` struct can then contain (or, *encapsulate*) a private property of type `[String: [String]]`,

   ```
   private var adjacencyDictionary: [String: [String]]
   ```

   and you should write methods that accesses, and (optionally) mutates the graph. e.g. `getNode(withName:)`, `getNeighboursOfNode(withName:)`, `addNode`, `addEdge` etc.

   You should not use a typealias here, because a graph ***is not*** a `[String: [String]]`. For example, the following `[String: [String]]` is not a (valid) graph:

   ```
   ["a": ["b"]]
   ```

Answer (score 5):

As per Documentation (found here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html):

> A type alias declaration introduces a named alias of an existing type
> into your program.

[...]

> After a type alias is declared, the aliased name can be used instead
> of the existing type everywhere in your program. The existing type can
> be a named type or a compound type. **Type aliases do not create new
> types;** they simply allow a name to refer to an existing type.

So in fact you are not defining a new type. You are just aliasing your type with another name to make this type more easy to use.

So in your case `Graph` is only another alias for the type `[String: [String]]` and doesn't introduce a new type for you.

So to achieve what you expected there are a lot of possibilities I guess. One way would be to wrap your `Graph` e.g. `[String: [String]]` into a struct or a class and write the extension for that struct / class. The way you would implement this highly depends on what you want to achieve.

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

A `typealias` is simply syntactic sugar. All type aliases get replaced by the actual type they alias at the beginning of compilation, so type aliases doesn't exist on the type-system level.

This is the reason behind the behaviour you are seeing - at the type system level, `Graph` is simply `[String:[String]]`, so defining any functions working with a `Graph` will actually work on the aliased type, namely, `[String:[String]]`.

If you want `Graph` to be a real type, you need to declare it like so - make it a `struct` or `class` with a backing storage of a `Dictionary`.

```
struct Graph {
    var storage: [String: [String]]
}

extension Graph {
    // Breadth First Search
    func bfs(from start: String, to finish: String) -> [String]? {
        // Implementation of this graph algorithm here
    }
}

let futurama: [String: [String]] ...
futurama.bfs() // This doesn't compile anymore
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answers below I came up with pretty neat approach.
That is combination of subscript, ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral and generics.

```
struct Graph<T> where T: Hashable {
    private var storage: [T: [T]]
    
    subscript(key: T) -> [T]! {
        storage[key]
    }
    
    func bfs(from start: T, to finish: T) -> [T]? {
        // Implementation of the algorithm here. 
    }
}

extension Graph: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral {

    init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (T, [T])...) {
        storage = .init(uniqueKeysWithValues: elements)
    }
}
```

And the code in my initial post will compile and work without any changes!
(except for generics stuff: `String` should be changed to `T` everywhere)